# Laravel 5.4: How to upload an image to the server with the user that uploaded it?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, migration

I am newbie learning laravel and i am trying to upload an image but i also need the user who uploaded the image.
Here is my photos table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedinteger('user_id')->index();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('photos');
}
```

This is my Photos model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id','title','image'
];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
public function upload(Request $request)// store the image 
{             
    $user=Auth::user()->id;
    $this->validate($request, [  
        'title' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',   
    ]);
    $input['image'] = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $input['image']);
    $input['title'] = $request->title;    

    Photos::create($input);
    return back()
    ->with('success','Image Uploaded successfully.')
    ->with($user);
}
```

The error  i get is :`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into 'photos' ('image', 'title', 'updated_at', 'created_at')`
The uploading is working without having a user_id row.
Can you please help me what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating the Photo with only a title and image. Needs a user_id param.

```
$input['title'] = $request->title;   
$input['user_id'] = $user;    

Photos::create($input);
```

Or

```
Auth::user()->photos()->create($input);
```